# Using who/whom/whose for taking a picture

Tags: relative-pronouns, who-whom

Which is the best way to ask this question?

> a. Who did he take a picture of at the party?
>
> b. Whom did he take a picture of at the party?
>
> c. Whose picture did he take at the party?

Answer (score 1):

In speech, I bet most natives would use a) before they even thought it through.

The entire who/whom thing is totally lacking from most people's linguistic ability so whether it's right or wrong, they never use whom; they simply don't know where to use it... so they don't.

If you tried to use b) you would then be in danger of drowning in the
'Can I use "Whom... of" or do I have to use "Of whom"?'
dilemma. "Of whom" makes you sound like someone's elderly grandma.

The way to avoid the dilemma entirely is to use c).

It's 'cheating' but it works ;-)